# why ValidationMassage errors does not show in view, but shows in firebug?

Tags: javascript, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, unobtrusive-validation

hi i have a partial view that is loaded in main view by clicking "edit" or "create" button.
it hast some dropdownlist thas fill by ViewBags.
i have activated unobtrasive javascript in webconfig and use it in my partial view.
when i debug main view in firebug, DropDownList's validationMessage errors just shows in html part of console and doesn't show in view by

> **"@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.groupID)"**

how can i solve it? Thanks.

**Edited: Sample codes**

```
  <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InsuranceInsurerID)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("InsuranceInsurerID", "Select...")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InsuranceInsurerID)
</div>

<div class="clr"></div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InsuranceTypeID)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
          .Name("InsuranceTypeID")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:210px" })
          .Placeholder("Select...")
          .DataTextField("TypeName")
          .DataValueField("TypeID")
          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetCascadeTypes", "Insurance");
              });
          })
    )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InsuranceTypeID)
</div>
```

ViewBags:

```
 var InsInsurer = db.INS_InsuranceWorkers
 .Where(m => m.InsWorkerTypeID == 1 && m.InsWorkerCreateUserID == userid)
 .Select(k => new { FullName = k.InsWorkerFirstName + " " + k.InsWorkerLastName,
 InsInsurerID = k.InsWorkerID }).ToList();

ViewBag.InsuranceInsurerID = new SelectList(InsInsurer, "InsInsurerID", "FullName");
```

kendo dropdown gets list by its actions.

Comment: Do you have in your form @Html.ValidationSummary()?

Comment: The other validations work?

Comment: @ВладиславНайденов Yes, I have  @Html.ValidationSummary(true) in my form.

Comment: @WannaCSharp yes, validation of Textboxes show correctly.

Comment: Can you show your code that displays the dropdown?

Comment: I think these are connected to db, but other control does not...